# xsl to retrieve other attribute values and append values into one attribute

Tags: css, xml, xslt, xpath

To start:

```
<test style="font:2px;color:#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" TOPMARGIN="5">style</test>
```

Using XSLT/XPATH, I copy everything over from my document

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But I'm not sure how to get this result using XSLT/XPATH:

```
<test style="background-color:#CCCCCC; margin-top:1;font:2px;color:#FFFFFF">style</test>
```

I think I'm failing at the XPATH.  This is my attempt at just retrieving bgColor:

```
<xsl:template match="@bgColor">
 <xsl:attribute name="style">
   <xsl:text>background-color:</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="../@style"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately, even this breaks when style is placed after bgColor in the original document. How can I append these deprecated attribute values into one inline style attribute?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution using one nice feature of XSLT -- the attribute value templates (AVT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <test style="{@style};background-color:{@bgcolor};margin-top:{@TOPMARGIN}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </test>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<test style="font:2px;color:#FFFFFF"
      bgcolor="#CCCCCC" TOPMARGIN="5">style</test>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<test style="font:2px;color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#CCCCCC;margin-top:5">style</test>
```

**Explanation**: Use of **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)**.

Comment: In this solution, <test style=";background-color:;margin-top:"> encapsulates the entire document and the text values of every node in the document are displayed within.

Comment: BUT, it does work for a single instance of test as stated in the question.

Comment: Let's say I'd like to apply this to every element and not just 'test'?

Comment: @Moyler: In this case you have to use `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute`. Ask a new question with the refined requirements and I'd be glad to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

May be not the best way, but it works:

```
<xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name() != 'bgcolor']"/>   
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@style">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>;background-color:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../@bgcolor"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```